# How can I re-enable microphone?

Tags: windows, laptop, microphone

I've an ASUS K42JP. I disabled the microphone device, and I have got the following message:

> Your microphone device has been removed

How can I re-enabled the microphone? It is an internal one.

Comment: What operating system is this? Is it an internal microphone? Please edit your post here http://superuser.com/posts/472218/edit

Comment: What operating system? Windows?

Comment: Can you also confirm if you disabled the microphone manually and if so, how.

Answer (score 18):

Enable it in device manager (that is, assuming you're on Windows).

Click Start (windows icon) right click on my Computer and select manage.

From the window on the left, click device manager.

(Or: click Start button, write 'device' in the Search area, then select 'Device Manager')

Locate your microphone in the list, right click on it and enable.

**EDIT**

Another suggestion is

- Open the Sound window,
- Click on the Recording tab, and then right-click in the space under the last recording device and click "Show Disabled Devices."
- You should now be able to see the option to enable it again

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work: There is no MICROPHONE in that list.
I'd UPDATE the sound device but it doesn't work either. Please help me

Comment: Writing in capitals doesn't help - I can read both lower case as well as upper and like most people, prefer lower. I will have another look into this for you.

Comment: Woooooowwwwwwwwwww... Dave Rook, you are fantastic... Thanks so much...You help me very nice... Some hours ago, i asked 2 softwares engineer and both of them can not help me... Thanks again... And oh, Sorry for capitals, i just want to bold that words... I'll always come to your site and thanks again... It works ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Windows 11 way to enable/allow audio device

On Windows 11, you could enable it through the Settings app.

1. Open **Settings** > **System** > **Sound**
   [image: Sound settings]
2. On the **Advanced** section, select **All sound devices**
   [image: All sound devices]
3. Select the disabled audio device
   [image: Device list]
4. Click **Allow** button
   [image: Allow]