# How to enable, disable, and switch between internal and external microphones in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

Im Windows 7, I use a Headset microphone to dictate to the computer. I was not sure at one point if the internal microphone was disabled or not and thought that maybe it was used instead of the headset microphone. I have tried to find a way to check this and search under Sound/Recording. There were two microphones there. I have identified the external one by the fact that if not connected the message 'not plugged in' appeared.

I have selected Properties and selected to disable it

[image]

Now a single (external) microphone is present under sound and there's no obvious setting there to re-enable it.

[image]

I went to  Device manager and found two devices there, both displaying only the 'Disable' option.

[image]

I want to know how to enable the internal microphone and also what is the proper management of microphones for the purpose presented above.

Comment: A piece of software can only use a single device normally ( i.e. Skype ) well written software allows you to choose which device you want to use.  Why can't you use that method, why are you, choosing to disable the device instead?

Comment: @Ramhound - i am new to the software that i use (Dragon Naturally Speaking) and was not sure if some problems of dictation were or not possibly because  both micros were activated

Comment: The version of DNS I have allows you to select which Microphone it will use.  That version is several years old.

Comment: @Ramhound - are they displayed with different names? mine appear with the same name ([here](http://imgur.com/kWr2hAr))

Comment: They are listed by the device name.  You are able to rename audio devices I did that with my Turtlebeach Headset.

Comment: @Ramhound - i did that.now it is clear to me that all this time both micros were open when i was dictating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part  of the question  - related to **re-enabling the disabled microphone** was answered [here](https://superuser.com/q/472218/162573).

So, I have a partial answer:
In the 'Sound/Recording' window, right-click and there's an option to see the disabled devices, which then can be enabled.

[image]

I had expected the internal microphone to be disabled automatically when an external one is connected. For an usb microphone, it seems that this is not the case, according to a comment under [here](https://superuser.com/q/510723/162573).

I do not know about the line-in jack. But mine are both active if both enabled

[image]

But a fair albeit manual method would be to **disable/enable the micro under 'Sound/Recording'** as I did in the first place.

Also, I think that it is more reasonable to un-check "Show disconected devices" on right click on 'Sound/Recording' window. In this way, a disconnected device would be absent from the list - as enabling/disabling an absent device is pointless.