# Fast switching between internal and external microphones in Windows

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, microphone

This question is closely related to [How to enable, disable, and switch between internal and external microphones in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/595494/how-to-enable-disable-and-switch-between-internal-and-external-microphones-in) but not exactly the same.

I need to constantly switch between an external bluetooth microphone and the internal microphone, during a Skype call. I would like to be able to do this by just doing a single click of the mouse or a single keyboard key. Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: Skype does not provide this functionality.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to achieve this system-wide? I don't really care if other apps are also switching.

Comment: See the linked question for the "system wide method", the problem you will face if you use that method, Skype will complain you don't have a micrphone.  Which means you will have to adjust your Skype settings, and if your going to do that, you might as well just change which microphone you want to use.

Comment: I understand. This is why I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for system-wide switching, and/or a way to create a keyboard shortcut.